# Predefined algorithm for rapid type analysis and variable type analysis

Tags: java, testing, code-analysis, dynamic-analysis

I'm trying to perform program analysis on the Java source file. Is there any predefined algorithm to perform variable type analysis and rapid type analysis?

Answer (score 4):

[Soot](http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/soot/) is an analysis framework for java.

["The Soot framework for Java program analysis:
a retrospective"](http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/publications/papers/2011-6/11.cetus.soot.pdf) says that the Spark module might be relevant to what you're doing:

> Spark implements a number of different call graph construction methods, including Class Hierarchy Analysis and Rapid
>   Type Analysis; however, we found that the most effective call
>   graph construction method proceeds on-the-ﬂy and builds the
>   call graph at the same time as it computes points-to sets,
>   starting with the CHA call graph as an initial approximation
>   for the set of reachable methods.

Answer (score 1):

[Wala](http://wala.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) is good static analysis framework

for  [RTA](https://github.com/wala/WALA/blob/30bc2858c4008b042fbc0d77209e114c7767c038/com.ibm.wala.core/src/com/ibm/wala/ipa/callgraph/impl/Util.java) : `Util.makeRTABuilder`

for  [VTA](https://github.com/wala/WALA/blob/30bc2858c4008b042fbc0d77209e114c7767c038/com.ibm.wala.core/src/com/ibm/wala/ipa/callgraph/impl/Util.java) : you have a 0-CFA wich do better than VTA, `Util.makeZeroCFABuilder`